# UML State Machine: Transition selection

Tags: uml, state-machine

I'm trying to collect informations to be able to program a correct transition selection algorithm for an UML State Machine.

The UML Superstructure Specification (15.3.12 StateMachine) states

> Only transitions that occur in mutually orthogonal regions may be fired simultaneously.

Does "mutually orthogonal" imply that the regions are on the same nesting level?

> For each state at a given level, all originating transitions are evaluated to determine if they are enabled.

This sounds to me like they have to be on the same nesting level. Right? Because if a transition is found on a certain nesting level, the search ends...

The seciton "Transition selection algorithm" once again is not totally clear to me:

> The only non-trivial issue is resolving transition conflicts across orthogonal states on all levels. This is resolved by terminating the search in each orthogonal
>   state once a transition inside any one of its components is fired.

To make this a little more haptic I created 2 models:

**Model 1**

[image: Model 1]

**Model 2**

[image: Model 2]

Active state configuration:

State1, State3, State4, State7

**Example 1a**

In case of an event Event1 which transitions fire?

a. Does only the one from State7 to State 5 fire?

b. Or also then one from State3 to State8?

Both variations would yield in a legal active state configuration.
But my understanding is, that a is correct

**Example 1b**

Same for model 2.

**Example 2a**

In case of an event Event2 which transitions fire?

a. Does only the one from State7 to State 5 fire?

b. Or also then one from State3 to State2?

In this case I would say that b would lead to an illegal active state configuration.

Does this mean the model is ill-formed or would only one of the transitions be fired?

**Example 2b**

Same for model 2. Any difference?

Answer (score 1):

I'd interpret mutually orthogonal to mean that the side effects of the transitions have no impact on each other.

So in either of your diagrams, the transitions triggered by Event1 can be deemed to be mutually orthogonal as the transitions are both contained within [A] and [B] and may be fired simultaneously. Event2 cannot as the transition from within [A] leaves A and State1 (and therefore also [B]).

Comment: So your interpretation would be:
In each orthogonal region (of the active state configuration) a transition, that can be enabled, is searched (from the inside out). If one is found, we're done for that orthogonal region and all its parents. Like this we find 0..* transitions.

Now if none of these transitions cause any of the target states of the other transitions to be left (that would be a "side effect") then the transitions fire?

And if one causes a side effect: Is the state machine ill-formed, do the transitions not fire, or does the transition search continue (I don't know how)?

Comment: The transition from State3 to State2 will have the following effect: exit State3, exit region [A], exit State1 (which will also cause region [B] to be exited), enter State2.

As this exits region [B], and the transition from State7 to State5 is in region [B], then they're not mutually orthogonal.

The UML spec, when stating that mutually orthogonal transitions "may be fired simultaneously" is suggesting an opportunity for optimisation.

Comment: If you did try to fire both simultaneously you would likely result in an illegal active state configuration as region [A] would be inactive and region [B] active.

So you'll need to evaluate and run them sequentially; if you select the transition in region [A] first, then as it exits State1, the one in region [B] will not fire.  If you tested region [B] first, its transition would fire, then the transition in region [A] would also fire.

Comment: What is not clear in the spec is the order in which you should test for transitions across orthogonal regions (in my implementation, https://github.com/steelbreeze/state.js, I do it in the same order the regions were created).

Comment: I didn't find a use of the term "mutually orthogonal  transitions" in the spec anywhere. Only of  mutually orthogonal regions. Superstructure specification (talking about conflicting transitions): "Only transitions that occur in mutually orthogonal regions may be fired simultaneously." This section talks about if transitions may fire at all. Execution order is not an issue here (yet). But I'd say the regions containing State3 and State7 are orthogonal.

Comment: Where I may have incorrectly discussed orthogonal transitions, I'd have better called them "conflicting transitions". See the full para from the spec: "Two transitions are said to conflict if they both exit the same state, or, more precisely, that the intersection of the set of states they exit is non-empty. Only transitions that occur in mutually orthogonal regions may be fired simultaneously. This constraint guarantees that the new active state configuration resulting from executing the set of transitions is well-formed."

Comment: So, in your model, Event2 from State3 will also exit State1, which in turn will exit region B, chaining the exiting of State4 and State7. As Event2 from State7 also exits State7, the "intersection of the set of states they exit is non-empty" due to both causing State7 to exit. Therefore they cannot be "fired simultaneously", but must be fired (and evaluated) sequentially.